# Clear user data or Clear cache on Phonegap android

Tags: android, ajax, caching, cordova

How can I clear user data or clear cache using PhoneGap and Android? The code below does not work. Where should I make the changes; On the HTML side or on the Java side? Also I'm accessing an AJAX request and on the second attempt of a PUT method, the data doesn't update so my primary suspect is the user data which Android stores. I have added `cache: false` on my AJAX request to ensure it does not store the cache. But it still does not work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I have this code based from another question.

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

So basically my POSActivity.java would look like this.

```
public class PocActivity extends DroidGap {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.is);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
    deleteCache(this);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDir(dir);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
}
```

Comment: I would start debugging the AJAX put request itself, since with cache:false, you should never get the same response twice - jQuery automatically adds a timestamp to such request, preventing it from being cached

Comment: ... also, I have successfully used the mentioned code to clear internal cache on an Android device, so I guess that code works just fine

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in your oncreate() method of activity file after loading index.html :

```
if (super.appView != null) {
     super.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a easy way to clear the cache in my Cordova Application, and found [this plugin](https://github.com/anrip/cordova-plugin-cache-clear) which clears the webView cache in Android using the following code:

```
// clear the cache
self.webView.clearCache(true);
```

And in iOS, runs in background and do this:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

To use the plugin, simply call `window.CacheClear(success, error);`

Luckily for me, it solved the problem I had.
Big thanks for the writer of this [cordova-plugin-cache-clear](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cache-clear)!